# Post request to api blocked by CORS policy

Tags: php, http, vue.js, axios

I am making a web app with Vue.js, in this web app people have to log in in order to receive an API key. I am making a post request to my API using axios, i am also sending 2 parameters with it, a name and a password. Whenever i submit my form it keeps giving me these errors:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost/Leerjaar%203/api/apikey/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

and

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/Leerjaar%203/api/apikey/' from origin 'http://localhost:8082' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

I have been stuck with this issue for months now, i stopped trying months ago but today i decided to get back to it and try again. I have tried setting the headers in my PHP file, but that doesnt seem to work either.

The method that makes the post request:

```
formSubmit(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let currentObj = this;
            axios.post('http://localhost/Leerjaar%203/api/apikey/', {
                docent: this.docentNaam,
                wachtwoord: this.wachtwoord
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                currentObj.output = response.data;
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {

            }); 
        }
```

My PHP API:

```
<?php    
session_start();
include "../errors.inc.php";
include "../credentials.inc.php";
include "../database.inc.php";

$docent = Docent();

if (!isset($_POST["wachtwoord"]))    fout(400, "wachtwoord ontbreekt");
if ($_POST["wachtwoord"] !== "test") fout(401, "wachtwoord incorrect");


header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://http://localhost:8081/', false);     
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo '{"apikey":"'.md5(md5($docent)).'"}';
```

My form:

```
<form @submit="formSubmit">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="docentNaam">Naam:</label>
                                <input v-model="docentNaam" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Docenten afkorting">

                                <label for="wachtwoord">Wachtwoord</label>
                                <input v-model="wachtwoord" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Wachtwoord">

                                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

This is the header i get back:

[image: Header]

I hope someone can help me with my problem, i feel like i have tried everything.

Comment: The best way to avoid CORS is not to have CORS (yes, I know, you want to slap me). The way I deal with it is that I use nginx to bring all the domains that play together under the same name. This means that I serve JS and PHP using `http://local.dev` (local.dev is a fake-name that I route to `127.0.0.1`, using `/etc/hosts` file, on Windows it's in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`). In web server config (I use nginx) I try to load the resource @ first server (in your case `:8082`) and then fallback to php. It works like a charm and no - you haven't tried everything! :)

Comment: [Here's a few examples how to set up an nginx proxy between nuxt and Laravel](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/nginx-proxy/). You can adjust the values to suit your needs.

Comment: The OPTIONS request is causing a 500 internal server failure in the server to which you're sending the request ー your API server. That 500 error is the problem you need to fix, and the cause of it has nothing to do with your CORS config on the API server. So the CORS error is actually irrelevant. You need to look through the server logs on your API server and see what.internal failure is happening in the server that causes it to end up responding with that 500 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORS is "cross origin resource sharing", see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests .  Basically, it is enforced by your browser. If the browser is blocking a cross-origin request, you some options:

- Make it not a cross origin request (by hosting everything at the same host and port)
- Satisfy the criteria for "simple request" so the browser let's the HTTP request through
- Implement the server side of CORS on whatever is hosting the POST form, which usually is a web server configuration chore (i.e. in an httpd.conf file), or by writing a custom OPTIONS request handler that will allow resource sharing to the page which initiates the POST request.

In the last two options, you probably want to think of what the "origin" will look like once your page is live. Allowing access to "*" will probably work, but is undoing the cross site scripting protection that the browser is helping you with.

Comment: i tried setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to * but the same errors keep coming up.

Comment: I'm a little confused about your app and API, actually. I see localhost, localhost: 8081, and localhost:8082 in the question? Which one is hosting the POST API, and which one is hosting the form that she's a POST request? The POST API needs to also respond to OPTIONS, with the "allow" response headers to tell your browser to let the POST request through. The error message in your question says "It does not have HTTP ok status" in reference to the OPTIONS request. So if you write that by hand, don't forget the set the response status to 200.

Comment: If you have some kind of proxy running to dev/debug, try turning that off and connect the page and API up directly.

Comment: The API is running on localhost, the application is running on localhost: 8082, although every time i restart my server, the localhost goes to a different port so that explains the localhost: 8081.At the time i wrote this question, i didnt update my code to localhost: 8082 yet. I also dont have a proxy running.

Comment: Ok, the thing with CORS is that each call to your API is really 2 calls to your API. The PHP code to handle the POST request only get called after the browser first makes an OPTIONS request. So make an OPTIONS request handler that returns the "allow" headers instead of in your POST response.  The error about status not being "ok" is probably because the status is 404 not found for the OPTIONS request.  (Or 405, if there is a resource there that doesn't handle OPTIONS.)

Comment: i tried sending custom header options with my post request but i'm still getting the same errors.